# SQL Get n last unique entries by date

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have an access database that I'm well aware is quite poorly designed, unfortunately it is what I must use. It looks a little like the following:

(Row# is not a column in the database, it's just there to help me describe what I'm after)

```
Row#    ID       Date       Misc
1       001    01/8/2013      A
2       001    01/8/2013      B
3       001    01/8/2013      C
4       002    02/8/2013      D
5       002    02/8/2013      A
6       003    04/8/2013      B
7       003    04/8/2013      D
8       003    04/8/2013      D
```

What I'm trying to do is obtain all information entered for the last n (by date) 'entries' where an 'entry' is all rows with a unique ID.

So if I want the last 1 entry I will get rows 6, 7 and 8. The last two entries will get me rows 4-8 etc.

I've tried to get the SN's needed in a subselect and then select all entries where those SN's appear, but I couldn't get it to work. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper Access syntax:

```
select * 
from t 
where ID in (select top 10 ID
             from t
             group by ID
             order by max([date]) desc
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm making progress, but this still got me iffy data.

Do you know why when I run just the subquery for the TOP 1 I'm getting 8 ID values back?

Comment: I've worked it out. It seems two values of 001-1 and 001-2 are counted as the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
select * 
from table 
where Date in (
    select distinct(Date) as unique_date from table order by unique_date DESC limit <num>
)
```

The idea is to use the subselect with a limit to only identify dates you care about.

EDIT: Some databases do not allow a limit in a subquery (I'm looking at you, mysql). In that case, you'll have to make a temporary table out of the subquery then select * from it.